# discrete mathematical structures 5th edition, 1.1 ex. 10 question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm working through this book and already hit a snag:

"Let A be a set and let B = {A, {A}}(Q1). Then since A and {A} are elements of B, we have A ∈ B and {A} ∈ B. It follows that {A} ⊆ B and {{A}} ⊆ B. However, it is not true that A ⊆ B. "

Ok question #1:  Why the extra braces on the second element of B? Why isn't it just written as {A, A} ? What do the brackets on {A} denote?

Question 2: Why is it not True that A ⊆ B? I think I'm just confused on the notation here. Because if {A} ⊆ B then why not A ⊆ B? Doesn't A denote a set?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $A$ is a set. However, $\{A\}$ is also a set - it's the set containing one element, and that element is $A$.

$\{\{A\}\}$ is *also* a set. It *also* contains one element, and that element is $\{A\}$, i.e. the set containing $A$ as its only element.

Importantly, while $A \in \{A\}$ and $\{A\} \in \{\{A\}\}$, it is *not* true that $A \in \{\{A\}\}$, and nor are $A \subset \{A\}$ or $\{A\} \subset \{\{A\}\}$ true.

Think of sets like boxes, and when you check the elements of the set you're allowed to open the box, but you *can't* look inside anything you find in there, you're only allowed to look at the labels that say what they are. So when you open the box labelled $B$, you see two items inside it - a box labelled $A$ and a box labelled $\{A\}$. If you open up the box labelled $A$, you might find a whole variety of things, but if you open up the box labelled $\{A\}$ you will find exactly *one* thing, which is another box labelled $A$ (which, if you opened *that* up, would contain the same things as the other box labelled $A$).